# Go, extensible system that classify files

Tags: go, dynamic, xml-parsing

I have the idea to create a "script" that will walk a directory tree to classify files and take actions (If it is a photo, upload to Flickr. If it is a video, move to a folder, ..).

I have no knwoledge of Go but would like to change that. The file discovery and classification don't seems to be the big part. *routines* and *channels* seems to be enough to have a non blocking system.

My main concern is more about the actions to take. I will certainly code some actions like "FlickrUpload" or "Shell" (for `mv`, `cp`, ..). But I would like to have a configurable system where I can attach an action to a mime type. I think an Xml structure could be nice to configure it and seems simple to parse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes">
<configuration>
  <file type="image/jpg">
    <action name="FlickrUpload" />
    <action name="Shell">
      mv ${file} /some/absolute/path/
    </action>
    <!-- or -->
    <FlickrUpload /> 
  </file>
</configuration>
```

But I have no idea on how to bind the action and his arguments (from Xml) to an `action` that will be an `interface` (unless you say other).

```
type action interface {
  execute(path string) error
}
```

Comment: This question is definitely a little broad but you can make it a better fit for SO by adding some code showing how you intend to actually parse the above XML the like.  Even if that code doesn't quite work yet that should help to narrow the focus of your question and make it something someone can really answer more concretely.

Comment: Aren't you reimplementing [FlexGet](https://flexget.com/)? Combine the [filesystem plugin](https://flexget.com/Plugins/filesystem) for input and use any filter and/or output plugins for actions.

Comment: @PabloLalloni I'm sure that this kind of tool already exists. But mine is just a concrete case to learn Go. Anyway, thanks for pointing FlexGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an XML stream or any other textual medium, you can only obtain text.
So your `mv ${file} /some/absolute/path/` is essentially text.

This means you will inevitably need to *parse* it before actually call
your real action on whatever you have parsed out.

Now you have two facets of this problem:

1. How to call certain Go code once an action is known.
2. How to pass "action arguments" data to it.

They are intertwined a bit—depending on how do you decide to solve (1).

The first approach to call Go function given its textual "handle" is to
simply have a map of such handles to functions, like this:

```
type Action func (...interface{}) error

var actions = map[string]Action {
    "mv": Move,
    "flickr": UploadToFlickr,
}

func Move(args ...interface{}) error {
    // implement
}

func UploadToFlickr(args ...interface{}) error {
    // implement
}
```

And now you dispatch your actions like

```
act, ok := actions[action_name]
if !ok {
  log.Fatalf("Config error: Unsupported action: %s\n', action_name)
}

err := act(action_args...)
if err != nil {
   // Handle
}
```

> Notice these `...` bits: they implement variadic functions
>   *and* allow to pass a slice of values to a variadic function.

The second approach is to go more strictly typed:

1. You define an interface:

   ```
   type Action interface {
       func Do(fname string) error
   }
   ```
2. Your configuration parsing code would produce values of concrete types
   like, say, `MoveAction`, `FlickrUploadAction`.

   All these types must implement a method `Do()` of the interface `Action`.

   By doing this, they automagically implment the said interface.
   This also means your condiguration parser could return values of that
   interface—something like this:

   ```
   func ConfigParser() (map[string]Action, error)
   ```

   …where `map[string]Action` would map MIME types of files
   to values of concrete types—such as `FlickrUploadAction`
   for files of type `image/png` and `MoveAction` for files of type
   `text/plain`.

To call an action, you lookup a map produced by that imaginary
`ConfigParser()` function using the file's MIME type and obtain a value
which implements the `Action` interface, so what's left is simply
calling its `Do()` method passing it the name of the actual file.

#### TL;DR

Read up on interfaces—they are super powerful and pervasive
in the standard library (look at those `io.Reader`s and `io.Writer`s).